# Svelte how to delay response while showing loader

Tags: svelte

I'm getting data from an API using a svelte store. I want to delay that response a second or 2 while the loader is shown. Is there a way to do that by adding a delay to the await or in the api fetch?

store.js...

```
export function getData(url) {
    
    const load = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        provider.set(data.provider)
        store.set(data)
    }
        load()
        return store;
}
```

app.js...

```
<script>
import Loading from "./components/Loading.svelte";

import { getData, store, apiUrl } from "./store";

const response = getData($apiUrl + "/api/" + item.replace('id-', ''));
<script>

    {#await $response}
        
        <div>
            <Loading />
        </div>
        
    {:then data}

       ....

    {:catch} 
        <Error/>
    {/await}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a timeout function in my store. Then adding it to the getData() function.

```
function showloader(millisec) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { resolve('') }, millisec);
    })
}

export function getData(url) {
    
    const load = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        await showloader(2000); // Added delay function here
        const data = await response.json();
        provider.set(data.provider)
        store.set(data)
    }
        load()
        return store;
}
```